# Is there something wrong with this github network graph?

Tags: github

This github network graph does not make sense to me.
https://github.com/zodiac/isicp/network

Beginning:
[image: beginning]

Middle:
[image: middle]

End:
[image: end]

There are no lines that go from zodiac to lowell, nor vice versa.

Is that normal?  Shouldn't these repositories have some common ancestor, and shouldn't that be indicated by a line that connects the two graphs?

If not, please explain what I don't understand about git, github, or this network graph feature.  Thank you!

Comment: In the second image, from the middle of the history, note the analogous structures.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess zodiac rebase-squashed all the commits before the currently first, thus breaking the link to lowells fork?

Conceptually, starting like this:

```
A-B-C  
 \D-E
```

and after squashing B into A:

```
  B'-C'   
  D -E
```

I haven't tried this so it's just a guess.

Comment: That sounds plausible.  If you or I or someone can verify that somehow (either by asking those users or finding/creating the same phenomenon) then I'd like to accept this answer.